# Waiting for a long process at server-side from a React app

Tags: reactjs, rest, connection-timeout

I'm building a frontend app which starts time consuming processes at server side. Which should be a right way to notify the client-side app when the process finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid connection timeout issues, in this scenario it's better to leave it to the client to check when the process has finished.

The best course of action for a REST API in this case is to return a response with a `202 (Accepted)` status code. This status code [means](https://httpstatuses.com/202):

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.

In the payload for this response, you can provide an endpoint that the client can use to check the status of request, for example:

```
{
    "task": {
        "href": "/api/jobs/1234",
        "id": "1234"
    }
}
```

The client can then use the provided endpoint to check for the status of the job processing the request. These responses should contain a 200 status code, and might contain a payload like this:

```
{
   "job" : {
     "@uri" : "/api/jobs/1234" ,
     "id" : "1234",
     "job-state" : "SCHEDULED",
     "percent-complete" : "0",
     "scheduled-start-time" : "11-05-2020 01:31:00 PM GMT",
     "start-time" : "",
     "end-time" : "",
     "result": ""
   }
}
```

If the purpose of this job is to generate a new resource, you can use the `result` key in the above payload to include a URL that points to the newly created resource. Similarly, if the job fails, you can include an `error` key to indicate why it failed.